# How to get speakers working in 10.04, when they are silent at any volume?

Tags: 10.04, speakers

Recently I installed Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit in my Sony VAIO machine and I figure out that speakers are totally disabled. At first I thought that the volume was to low, but that wasn't the case.

I even update and upgrade, but the problem remains.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

---

Executing the command lspci, I get the following output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0104 (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0126 (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Device 1e31 (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 1e3a (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Device 1e2d (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 1e20 (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1e10 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1e12 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1e14 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Device 1e26 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1e59 (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 1e03 (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 1e22 (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. Device 0032 (rev 01)
02:00.0 Class ff00: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5209 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

Comment: I'm looking here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=82294

can you do as suggested in this comment there?
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=82294#p445024

Comment: give the new output of the Audio thing (: I'm still reading (:

Comment: Thank Eliah! It's much more better ^^ .
And "user" [Your name for this moments (: ], as I saw in the second page, and in the other thread: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=90526 , updating the kernel solved it. But, I don't know how to guide you. Does anyone can help him updating the kernel?

And, "user", I can't tell what the messege you got "Synaptics hardware cannot be queried" means.

Comment: Sorry for using the Answer button, it was not possible to fit it in comments. 
Ok yinon, I'll post the thread.
The output for lspci | Audio is
`00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 1e20 (rev 04)`

Comment: Well, I see no change or more infirmation, did you used this: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=82294#p445024

"1e20 is the supposed device id of your sound card. The fact that your seeing it means your pci id lookup table is a bit dated (stable...). Running $ sudo update-pciids should pull the latest pci ids, and your lspci output should be a bit more descriptive.".

You may need to update the kernel, Edit your title and ask to update the kernel, or open another Question and post it's link here.

Comment: VAG, from what I can see, Ubuntu 10.04 can't recognize it. Maybe a kernel update will help, but it will be easier to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ^^ . 12.04 is great. Fast and stable. You can also try 12.10, but I think it's buggy in relation to 12.04 LTS. And if you installed 10.04, you're looking for stability (: What do you say? wanna try 12.04?
you can install Gnome2 there also (:

Comment: to install Gnome2, in the terminal [also Ctrl+Alt+T to topen it]: sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback

Comment: Yes, I could install it so, but I like to search and learn through it.. So I prefer to get tired.. I'll change it as my last option. I'll try to update the kernel.

Comment: OK ^^ you know how to update your kernel? You can create a New Post and give here a link (: 

also, try to run 12.04 from a disk/USB and see if the sounds works.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lscpi` output is a little weird. Run the following in the terminal:

```
sudo update-pciids
```

Once it's done, check out [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting). Read and go through the steps 5, 6, and 7. If the problem persists go through the "Manual Installation" section.

Comment: Sometimes miracles happen!! Well, my ubuntu's 10.04 speakers finally work. I didn't do anything about it. I just open my pc and I surprised to hear ( and finally know ) the sound of log in on ubuntu. Though, it was a matter of time to decide installing 12.04. The environment is much cooler!! 

Anyway, I appreciate all your effort!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the volume Icon, and from there to the setting-window ["Audio settings"?].
change there the Device you want to use. you should have a list to choose [click and choose]. It may be called "Port" [I'm using xfce and Have Hebrew [עברית ^^ ], that why I'm not sure how things called (: ].

Did that help? Try to log-out and in.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem though, is that in the Device there is no device to select. Strange.

Comment: Great, I'm not expert, but we have a direction that the speakers are not detected by the system [Am i Right?]

Please run "lspci" in the terminal (without ""), and post the output here.

linux friends, I'll need help helping here, Please stay and give some advices and solutions (:

Comment: That's right, they do not detected. In addition, I want to mention here that during log in I have a message on the black screen mentioning that "Synaptics hardware cannot be queried".